# Shopify out of stock message

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

In my web application, I need the client being able to dinamically change the out of stock message, but inside the own web application (not from a web backoffice).

I know you can change that message in `product.liquid` template but, is there some way to change it in another way? Maybe that template can access an external resource to retrieve the message, maybe something like a web service can rewrite that value in the template...

I was planning to edit `product.liquid` and get the message from another server with AJAX, but the CORS problems arises then...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: No success with js and cookies?

Comment: I've edited my original post

Comment: yes it work, using ajax cross domain.

Comment: you can add the out of stock message in theme's language section (in backend).